# Strange behaviour when adding values to elements of a python list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a game which randomly chooses a "room" layout from a set and then puts it in 1 of 4 positions on the screen. My code to achieve this is:

```
room_spawns = [[randint(0, 5)] for a in range(4)]

for i in range(0, 4):
    these_segments = []
    these_shapes = []
    if i == 1:
        modifier = [800, 0]
    elif i == 2:
        modifier = [0, 448]
    elif i == 3:
        modifier = [800, 448]
    else:
        modifier = [0, 0]
    if room_spawns[i] == 0:
        these_segments = room_1_segments
        these_shapes = room_1_shapes

    elif room_spawns[i] == 1:
        these_segments = room_2_segments
        these_shapes = room_2_shapes

    elif room_spawns[i] == 2:
        these_segments = room_3_segments
        these_shapes = room_3_shapes

    elif room_spawns[i] == 3:
        these_segments = room_4_segments
        these_shapes = room_4_shapes

    elif room_spawns[i] == 4:
        these_segments = room_5_segments
        these_shapes = room_5_shapes

    elif room_spawns[i] == 5:
        these_segments = room_6_segments
        these_shapes = room_6_shapes

    for z in range(0, len(these_segments)):
        these_segments[z][0] += modifier[0]
        these_segments[z][1] += modifier[1]

    for x in range(0, len(these_shapes)):
        these_shapes[x][0][0] += modifier[0]
        these_shapes[x][0][1] += modifier[1]
        these_shapes[x][1][0] += modifier[0]
        these_shapes[x][1][1] += modifier[1]

    segments.append(these_segments)
    shapes.extend(these_shapes)
```

However, whenever a room which is the same as one chosen previously is chosen, its value is increased by the modifier value more than once and as such doesn't appear on screen. Can anybody please explain why this happens, and how it could be fixed.

Edit: After further research and debugging, for some reason, when adding the modifier value to these_segments and these_shapes, that same value is also added to the identical values already in segments and shapes, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmdRU.jpg). It appears as though the values of room_2_segments themselves have been modified. Does anybody know why this is and how it could be prevented?

Comment: `room_spawns` is a list of `length 1`, does not the above code raise `IndexError`?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `room_spawns` is a list with length of one (it contains one boolean). Thus, `room_spawns[0]` will return that boolean, but for `i`>0 you get an `IndexError`.

Also, note that `[randint(0, 5)] in range(4)` will always return `False` because `[randint(0,5)]` is not an integer, it's a list with only one element. And since `room_spawns` is a list with this boolean, it will always be equal to `[False]`.

Maybe you want `room_spawns` to be a list with more than one element?

Comment: Yeah I do that part is way wrong, but even when tested properly I still run into the issue I outlined above. For example if room_spawns is set as [1,1,2,3] it doesn't act as intended